# Internet Explorer css Error

Tags: css, internet-explorer

My tutorial site works fine on google chrome but when i try to open it with any kind of internet explorer i can not see some part of visul items.

All information of my design exist in css file. However being gray of right part can be observed but on the other hand i can't see navigation bar.

I put my some codes. It is high possible to have any link between these code and this situation.

At the beginning:

```
<!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/tempPage00.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" --><!doctype html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<html>
<title>Tutorials</title>
...

<link href="styles/mainStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

For more you can check: http://www.soccerforecast.com/Tutorials/SFUnderCons/currentForecasts.php

I don't have 10 reputation so i can't put direct image to this site so link is: http://postimage.org/image/y94bk7afb/

I don't usualy control my site with different kind of browser, now i recommend to do this everyday. Now i don't have any idea which code make this situation.  :)

Comment: Your browser comes with debugging tools for HTML/CSS/JS. At least look at their error reports before asking SO to fix your code.

Comment: I coudn't think there may be a developper tool to check in ie. I used always google chrome for these. Thanks.

Comment: Using the validator doesn't require a developer tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yout HTML is a little messed up.

Fix these things and it might help:

1. Place your HTML tag before the HEAD tag but after the DOCTYPE tag.
2. Place a closing HTML tag at the very end of your document.
3. In the TABLE you have towards the end of your page you have an extra closing TR tag.
4. The comment before your DOCTYPE will possibly cause problems too.

Try running your site through a validator to check for errors like these.

HTML: http://validator.w3.org/

CSS: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a comment before your doctype declaration.

This is forcing the page into [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) if you remove that comment you should be ok.

```
<!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/tempPage00.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<!doctype html>
<head>
```

Edit... The head and html tags are the wrong way round also.